# Invariant Violation: Invalid prop 'color' supplied

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I defined colors constants:

```
export const COLORS = {
  red: '#E90716',
  black: '#000000',
  // other colors
}
```

In a component file I import it:

```
import {COLORS} from '../colors.js'
```

In the component, I have nested `Text` element in which I would like to apply the red color:

```
return (
<View>
<Text>
        Blabla
        <Text
          style={styles.myText}>
          I am red.
        </Text>
      </Text>
</View>
);
...

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  myText: {
    color: COLORS.red,
  },
});
```

But when I run the app, I got error:

```
Invariant Violation: Invalid prop 'color' supplied to `StyleSheet myText`: E90716
```

Why is that error? How to use color code I defined as constant for a `Text` element?

**===== UPDATE ====**

But if I change to use hardcoded color code it works.

e.g.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  myText: {
    color: 'red', 
  },
});
```

It also works if I am not using hex code in COLORS, e.g.

```
// it works as well!
export const COLORS = {
   red: 'red'
}
```

Why? Why the color constant I defined with hex value doesn't work?

Comment: Did you debug and see what `COLORS.red` is returning?

Comment: Please see my update. Only when using the hex value as color code the issue comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested with this code ,its working, you can check the link [expo-link](https://snack.expo.io/bMA1ZIB1bL).

i believe you are using styles.myText in some other component like View or something , hence color is not a style attribute there, hence the error. do check once.

UPDATE:

are you storin the colors like these with the quotes? or are you not giving quotes:

```
export const COLORS = {
  red: '#E90716',

}
```

or

```
export const COLORS = {
  red: #E90716,
 
}
```

Feel free for doubts.Hope it helps

Comment: No, it is not because of that, if I change to hardcoded color code, it works fine. Problem is in the hex color code. But I don't know where is wrong. Please see my update.

Comment: @Leem.fin please check. the updated answer,i think this is a trivial thing

Comment: My bad, I missed the '#' in the quoted string. But anyway, nice guidance, I accept your answer. Thanks!