# Invariant Violation: Invalid prop 'color' supplied if error like this

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

```html
<Text style={{
    fontSize: 20,
    color: "#088F8F",
    paddingHorizontal: 6,
    fontWeight: "600",
    textAlign: "center",
  }}>
```

Comment: answer change the position of color

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invariant Violation: Invalid prop 'color' supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62795110/invariant-violation-invalid-prop-color-supplied)

Comment: That should not causing any issue, can you post a full sample.

Answer (score -1):

You should change the position of the color line like this

```
<Text style={{
                fontSize: 20,

                paddingHorizontal: 6,
                fontWeight: "600",
                textAlign: "center",
                color: "#088F8F",
              }}
```